LRP method with captum Library
I'm encountering error
AttributeError (AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'rule')

when attempting to apply the LRP method to a VGG-16 model for score calculation using Captum library.
Here are the steps I'm following:
I've loaded the CIFAR-10 dataset along with the VGG-16 model.
import torch
from torchvision import models, transforms, datasets
from captum.attr import LayerLRP
import numpy as np

# Load CIFAR-10 dataset
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])

testset = datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=100, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

# Load the pre-trained VGG-16 model
model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
model.eval()

I'm attempting to compute the LRP scores using the following approach:
# Initialize Captum's LayerLRP for VGG-16
layer_lrp = LayerLRP(model, model.features)

# Compute LRP scores for the test data
def get_lrp_scores(data_loader):
    lrp_scores = []
    for inputs, labels in data_loader:
        inputs = inputs.requires_grad_()
        attribution = layer_lrp.attribute(inputs, target=labels)
        lrp_scores.append(attribution.detach().numpy())
    return np.concatenate(lrp_scores, axis=0)

lrp_scores = get_lrp_scores(testloader)

print("Shape of LRP scores:", lrp_scores.shape)

The problem:
<ipython-input-33-fbab3259063c> in get_lrp_scores(data_loader)
     25     for inputs, labels in data_loader:
     26         inputs = inputs.requires_grad_()
---> 27         attribution = layer_lrp.attribute(inputs, target=labels)
     28         lrp_scores.append(attribution.detach().numpy())
     29     return np.concatenate(lrp_scores, axis=0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/captum/attr/_core/layer/layer_lrp.py in attribute(self, inputs, target, additional_forward_args, return_convergence_delta, attribute_to_layer_input, verbose)
    231                 self._forward_fn_wrapper, inputs, target, additional_forward_args
    232             )
--> 233             relevances = self._get_output_relevance(output)
    234         finally:
    235             self._restore_model()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/captum/attr/_core/layer/layer_lrp.py in _get_output_relevance(self, output)
    280             return relevances
    281         else:
--> 282             return self._get_single_output_relevance(self.layer, output)
    283 
    284     @staticmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/captum/attr/_core/layer/layer_lrp.py in _get_single_output_relevance(self, layer, output)
    256             normalized_relevances = layer.rule.relevance_input
    257         else:
--> 258             normalized_relevances = layer.rule.relevance_output
    259         key_list = _sort_key_list(list(normalized_relevances.keys()), self.device_ids)
    260         normalized_relevances = _reduce_list(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1707             if name in modules:
   1708                 return modules[name]
-> 1709         raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")
   1710 
   1711     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Union[Tensor, 'Module']) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'rule'

Could you please provide guidance on resolving this issue?
